# Update a column using subquery or join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update the 'DA_ArticleDetails' column of table1 using the resul from the select query. I tried something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET [DA_ArticleDetails] =
(
select RIGHT([DA_ArticleDetails], 8000)
from table1
)
```

but its giving  error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Could anyone help me how to update the column?

Comment: It seems that you are wanting to change the datatype from MAX to 8000? Why not just alter the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call the following query

```
UPDATE table1 
SET [DA_ArticleDetails] =RIGHT([DA_ArticleDetails], 8000)
```

Comment: Thank you.
This query does helped.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table1 
SET [DA_ArticleDetails] = RIGHT([DA_ArticleDetails], 8000)
from table1
```

Comment: Don't need the FROM for this.